# wrap text in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

### I want text with location icon in last in row, When my location text will be sort then it should be in last in that row and when location text will be long then it should be wrap text and show dotted,

I want text with location icon in last in row, When my location text will be sort then it should be in last in that row and when location text will be long then it should be wrap text and show dotted,

how to do it,

```
locationView() {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(16, 20, 16, 0),


      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: [
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  bellazTitle("Hey, Emily", 22),
                ],
              ),
              SizedBox(width: 10,),
              Container(
                // width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width-160,
                child: Row(
                  // mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                  children: [
                    Image.asset(
                      "lib/Assets/location.png",
                      height: 22,
                      width: 16,
                    ),
                    featureName == null
                        ? Container()
                        : Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 8.0),
                            child: Column(
                              children: [
                                Container(
                                  // color: Colors.red,
                                  // width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width-190,
                                  child: Text(
                                    // "${featureName}, ${locality}",
                                    "as fhf sdfghj xchjk sdfghjk dfghjk zj ",
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                      color: apptitleColor,
                                      fontSize: t4Size,

                                    ),maxLines: 1,
                                    overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          )
                  ],
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 2.0),
            child: Text(
              "Welcome to Bellaz!",
              style: TextStyle(
                color: extraLightColor,
                fontSize: t5Size,
              ),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

[image]

Comment: is `locationView()` inside column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is to set a MAX_LOCATION_TXT_LEN then display only the first chars if it passed it

```
static const MAX_LOCATION_TXT_LEN = 20;
String longTxt ="This text is too long";

String shortTxt = longTxt.length <= MAX_LOCATION_TXT_LEN ? longTxt : longTxt.substring(0, MAX_LOCATION_TXT_LEN) + "...";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the Flexible or Expanded widget to wrap your text.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).